# Developing alphabetical scrolling in ionic framework

Tags: scroll, ionic-framework

I am new to ionic framework and is designing a scrolling list based on alphabetical ordering.Most of the matter available are related to android and ios but nothing substantial for ionic..

Answer (score 1):

Navneet Anand, You can a list with ng-repat and use the "order by" function to sort the list in  alphabetical order.
Example :
 Use Ionic Item for list with orderBy tag :

```
<ion-item collection-repeat="item in main.items | orderBy:'toString()'">
```

Full example code : http://codepen.io/sarbwarraich/pen/PNRPpN

I think it will help you to create a list with alphabetical ordering.